# MySQL use result for WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have query

```
SELECT all_users,
       employed_users,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unemployed_users
    FROM users
       WHERE status = 1
```

I added filter to the webpage unemployed_min and unemployed_max numeric, is there way to filter in MySQL only without involving PHP say when you select on page

```
unemployed_min = 1
unemployed_max = 5
```

when i do

```
SELECT all_users,
       employed_users,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unemployed_users
    FROM users
       WHERE status = 1
         AND unemployed_users > 1 AND unemployed_users < 5
```

or

```
SELECT all_users,
       employed_users,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unemployed_users
    FROM users
       WHERE status = 1
         AND SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 
         AND SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 5
```

does not work

**EDIT:** 
it saying "**Invalid use of group function**" however i dont use group statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `having` clause, because you want to filter on an aggregated expression:

```
SELECT all_users,
       employment_terminated,
       unemployment_collected,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unemployed_users
FROM users
WHERE status = 1
HAVING unemployed_users > 1 AND unemployed_users < 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious grouping issue with your queries. You're using an aggregated function and not grouping by any field while selecting a few. That means you will only get one row containing an unpredictable value in `all_users` and `employed_users`.

First, you will have to define the proper grouping (maybe this?)

```
GROUP BY all_users, employed_users
```

Then, if you need to filter the groups you can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING unemployed_users > 1 AND unemployed_users < 5
```

You can also simplify the `SUM` this way:

```
SUM(employment_one_terminated = 1 OR employment_two_terminated = 1)
```

You can even remove the `= 1` if those are boolean values.

The final query should look very similar to this:

```
SELECT all_users, employed_users,
  SUM(employment_one_terminated OR employment_two_terminated) AS unemployed_users
FROM users
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY all_users, employed_users
HAVING unemployed_users > 1 AND unemployed_users < 5
```